# Difference between Calling Static function from Object and Class itself

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, static, singleton

I was learning singleton design pattern and I did understand the concept. However, I have a doubt in the following code : -

```
class Token
{
    private static int i = 5;
    private static Token obj = new Token();

//Private Constructor
    private Token()
    {
    }

//Returning the singleton object
    public static Token getObject()
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public static int getValue()
    {
        return i;
    }
}

public class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Token obj = Token.getObject();

        System.out.println("Without object " + Token.getValue());
        System.out.println("With object " + obj.getValue());
    }
}
```

The instance variable i gets printed in both the cases -

```
Without object 5
With object 5
```

What is the difference between the two ways of getting instance variable and which one is recommended?

Comment: There is no "instance variable `i`" in your code. When a field is static, it is not an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a static variable that belongs to class `Token` so it'll have the same value for all objects that are of type `Token`.

For all practical purposes, `obj.getValue()` is the same as `Token.getValue()` and you could use either, but for better readability, use `Token.getValue()` as it reinforces the idea that the static variable `i` and static method `getValue()` belong to the class as a whole and not to certain objects of that class.

Comment: Alright, I get the concept.. if there would have been a non-static private variable "val", then to access it we would have required the object - obj. Else, for all the static variables, both the methods are actually the same. Right?

Answer (score 1):

In fact in `obj` you have reference to your singleton. So calling `Token.getValue()` reference to same obj as `obj.getValue()`

Answer (score 1):

There is little difference, for instance access you need the actual instance, which you don't always have.

As for preference it depends on who you ask. For me static fields and methods should be accessed using the class not instance - this clearly shows that it is static.